# How to keep Display Suite CSS classes in code?

Tags: display-suite

I'm using `DS` in my D7 project along `Features`, so I've been able to keep all my new DS layouts, CCK, etc. in code, by generating a custom feature.

All good there... until I had to add some custom CSS classes to Display Suite:

[image]

Can't see how these values can be exported in code to persist in my project, rather than my DB. Nothing from the `feature` module either.

Is this actually possible? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you use Drupal 7, have you checked out the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) and [Strongarm](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) modules? Both modules allow you to export most configs as code.

Comment: By installing Strongarm I was able to select the `ds_classes_fields` variable and export it with my feature. Thanks!